# How to create resource counter e.g /post/1 in node.js using mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

Does anyone know how to implement e.g. post counter to mongo db? I think I would do

- accept /post with data
- get mongo collection.count
- add this custom id as {id: collection.count + 1}

but now I don't really know what will happen if 2 /posts will come at the same time. It will be queued in db? Or it will has 2 same fake id?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `id` field as unique to handle the case where 2 posts come at the same time...*but*, you will lose one document, since MongoDB won't allow another object for the same `id`.

You will have to write another piece of code to handle that case, which will be much more complex than a simple create operation.

Ideally, you shouldn't use a separate field in this way, unless it is required by your application and there is no alternative.

Here are a few caveats of using this approach:

- For each post received, there are 2 DB operations being performed.
- To prevent the loss of documents when the `id` field is set to unique, you will have to add another block of code, which might have to make a 3rd DB call to finally be stored in the database

**Bottom line: Always use `_id` unless you have a reason not to do so.**